# How do I wrap my text around my image AND keep my caption beneath the image?

Tags: html, css

I want an image on the left with my article wrapped around the image AND my caption at the bottom. But when I enter my code, it ends up looking like this:

https://i.ibb.co/8Nhk44B/Untitled.png

Notice the caption is up top instead of underneath the image.

How would I correct this? I apologize for the rather ominous topic

```css
.square {}

.square img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

.box {
  font-size: x-small;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: x-small;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h2>
    <a href="post003.html" class="h2Title">Is this the skull of Mary Magdalene?</a>
  </h2>
  <h5>Jonathan Milano, <a href="blog.html">May 1, 2021</a></h5>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="square">
      <a href="post003.html">
        <img src="https://milanothan.files.wordpress.com/2021/05/disn_d5xcaazpjz-1-1.jpg" width="50%" style="float: left;" alt="Mary Magdalene’s skull on 
    display in France" />
        <p class="caption" style="vertical-align: bottom; !important">Mary Magdalene’s supposed skull on display in Southern France.<br> Copyright © 2021 <a href="http://www.magdalenepublishing.org/skull-mary-magdalene/" class="ulLink" target="_blank">Magdalene Publishing</a>
        </p>
      </a>


      <p>Although Mary Magdalene’s historic existence is still under debate today, Christian text from sources including the New Testament tell us that Mary of Magdala (her home village on the shore of the Sea of Gailee) played a significant role in the
        life of Jesus Christ and the foundations of Christianity as it is known today.
        <br><br> According to legend, Mary was one of the women that stayed with Jesus even up to crucifixion. She is said to be the first one whom Jesus appeared to after resurrection. Other early Christian texts raise her status even more in that after
        the death of Christ she is considered almost an apostle rivaling the status of Saint Peter.</p>
      <p>The New Testament tells us that the followers of Christ were prosecuted from the Holy Land after his death and many of them were forced out to sea in small ships without sail or rudder where they were left to perish on their own. The most common
        version of the legend states that Mary Magdalene was sent with Mary Salomé, Mary Jacobé, Martha, Lazarus, Maximin, and their Egyptian servant Sara into one of these ships.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't looked too closely but have you tried wrapping the image and the paragraph below it in a div?

Comment: Give link to your image uploaded

Comment: link to image used https://milanothan.files.wordpress.com/2021/05/disn_d5xcaazpjz-1-1.jpg

Comment: Pretty sure that is not possible. Plus it looks REALLY odd. Maybe something with shape-outside but I am doubtful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options:

add float and width for the .caption

```css
.square {
}


.square img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  width:50%;
}


.box {
  font-size: x-small;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

.caption {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: x-small;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  padding:0 20px 0 0;
}
a{color:#333;}
```

```html
<div class="card">
            <h2><a href="post003.html" class="h2Title">Is this the skull of Mary Magdalene?</a></h2>
            <h5>Jonathan Milano, <a href="blog.html">May 1, 2021</a></h5>

            <div class="box">
              <div class="square">
              
                
                  <a href="post003.html">
                <img src="https://milanothan.files.wordpress.com/2021/05/disn_d5xcaazpjz-1-1.jpg" width="50%" style="float: left;" alt="Mary Magdalene’s skull on 
                display in France" /><p class="caption" style="vertical-align: bottom; !important">Mary Magdalene’s supposed skull on display in Southern France.<br>
                  Copyright © 2021 <a href="http://www.magdalenepublishing.org/skull-mary-magdalene/" class="ulLink" 
                  target="_blank">Magdalene Publishing</a></p></a>
                

                <p>Although Mary Magdalene’s historic existence is still under debate today, Christian 
                  text from sources including the New Testament tell us that Mary of Magdala 
                  (her home village on the shore of the Sea of Gailee) played a significant role 
                  in the life of Jesus Christ and the foundations of Christianity as it is known today.
                  <br><br>
                  According to legend, Mary was one of the women that stayed with Jesus even up to 
                  crucifixion. She is said to be the first one whom Jesus appeared to after resurrection. 
                  Other early Christian texts raise her status even more in that after the death of Christ 
                  she is considered almost an apostle rivaling the status of Saint Peter.</p>
                  <p>The New Testament tells us that the followers of Christ were prosecuted  from the Holy Land after his death and many of them were forced out to sea in small ships without sail or rudder where they were left to perish on their own. The most common version of the legend states that Mary Magdalene was sent with Mary Salomé, Mary Jacobé, Martha, Lazarus, Maximin, and their Egyptian servant Sara into one of these ships.</p>
                
                
                
              
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one option:

```css
.square {
}


.square img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  width:50%;
}


.box {
  font-size: x-small;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

.caption {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: x-small;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  padding:0 20px 0 0;
}
a{color:#333;}
```

```html
<div class="card">
            <h2><a href="post003.html" class="h2Title">Is this the skull of Mary Magdalene?</a></h2>
            

            <div class="box">
              <div class="square">
              
                
                  <a href="post003.html">
                <img src="https://milanothan.files.wordpress.com/2021/05/disn_d5xcaazpjz-1-1.jpg" width="50%" style="float: left;" alt="Mary Magdalene’s skull on 
                display in France" /><p class="caption" style="vertical-align: bottom; !important">Mary Magdalene’s supposed skull on display in Southern France.<br>
                  Copyright © 2021 <a href="http://www.magdalenepublishing.org/skull-mary-magdalene/" class="ulLink" 
                  target="_blank">Magdalene Publishing</a></p></a>
                

                <p>Although Mary Magdalene’s historic existence is still under debate today, Christian 
                  text from sources including the New Testament tell us that Mary of Magdala 
                  (her home village on the shore of the Sea of Gailee) played a significant role 
                  in the life of Jesus Christ and the foundations of Christianity as it is known today.
                  <br><br>
                  According to legend, Mary was one of the women that stayed with Jesus even up to 
                  crucifixion. She is said to be the first one whom Jesus appeared to after resurrection. 
                  Other early Christian texts raise her status even more in that after the death of Christ 
                  she is considered almost an apostle rivaling the status of Saint Peter.</p>
                  <p>The New Testament tells us that the followers of Christ were prosecuted  from the Holy Land after his death and many of them were forced out to sea in small ships without sail or rudder where they were left to perish on their own. The most common version of the legend states that Mary Magdalene was sent with Mary Salomé, Mary Jacobé, Martha, Lazarus, Maximin, and their Egyptian servant Sara into one of these ships.</p>
                
                
                
              <h5>Jonathan Milano, <a href="blog.html">May 1, 2021</a></h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```